# LG NotificationCompat missing actions

Tags: android, notifications

I have a problem with heads up notification system on LG devices with Lollipop OS. I'm using a notification with MAX priority to notify the user of an incoming call by setting a full screen pending intent on it to open the actual incoming call screen activity and two action buttons for Answer/Reject.

In some random (?!) cases the notification does present itself, but without the actions. Swiping the notification with one/two fingers does not expand the actions as is a suggested solution for some `NotificationCompat` mechanisms. They just aren't there. This happens only on LG Lollipop phones and only in random cases, so I cannot figure out what the problem is.

Any solutions here?

Here is the code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
        .setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.app_main))
        .setContentIntent(inCallPendingIntent)
        .setFullScreenIntent(inCallPendingIntent, true)
        .setContentTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.notification_incoming_call))
        .setContentText(displayName)
        .setDefaults(0)
        .setTicker(mContext.getString(R.string.notification_incoming_call))
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.stat_sys_phone_call)
        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
        .setUsesChronometer(false)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_remove_gray,
                mContext.getString(R.string.notification_incoming_call_reject),
                rejectPendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_call_gray,
                mContext.getString(R.string.notification_incoming_call_accept),
                acceptPendingIntent)
        ;
```

Here is the screenshot of the problem (It's taken on Samsung and edited to best represent the issue)

[image: NotificationCompat]

Comment: So nobody got this issue?

Comment: You are not alone here, I'm experiencing the same issue on my S3, for the some unknown reason sometimes I have the action, sometimes - no

Comment: I assume, you haven't found any solutions or workarounds for it?

Comment: yes you're right. I didn't found the cause of the problem, it is random